# Use iptables to block ssh

Tags: ssh, iptables

I have a linux machine (turnkey core 14.2) with two network cards.

`eth0` is a public ip, WAN (let's call it `123.123.123.123`).

`eth1` is my network, LAN.

I would like to block `SSH` from the WAN with `iptables`.

I use the command

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 123.123.123.123 --dport 22 -j DROP
```

If I then write

```
sudo iptables -L
```

I get the answer

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target   prot opt source            destination

DROP     tcp  --  123.123.123.123   anywhere      tcp dpt:ssh
```

Problem is that I'm not blocked if I use `PuTTY` to connect to 123.123.123.123.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the output of `iptables-save` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are matching traffic by source address (`-s` option), instead of destination address (`-d` option), which is why your rule doesn't drop any traffic from other hosts.

You can also match by input interface (instead of address) with `-i` option. For example to drop all incoming traffic to port *22* for *eth0*:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thnx. I mixed up -s & -d. -i worked also.

Answer (score 1):

As @sebasth answered, because you want to block traffic trying to connect to your public IP `123.123.123.123` then would be the following schema:

```
source `INTERNET`
destination `123.123.123.123`
```

So you might change the `-s` (source) to `-d` (destination)

Regarding your `iptables` line, I suggest to add it with the `-I` (Insert) instead of `-A` (Append) because if you have for any reason an old rule accepting all incoming traffic to `port 22`, then the `-A` will add the rule at the very end of your `iptables` and it would take the very first rule it finds.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -d 123.123.123.123/32 --dport 22 -j DROP
```

From `man iptables`

> -A, --append chain rule-specification
>                 Append one or more rules to the end of the selected chain.  When the source and/or  destination  names  resolve  to  more  than  one
>                 address, a rule will be added for each possible address combination.
>
> -I, --insert chain [rulenum] rule-specification
>                 Insert  one  or  more  rules  in  the  selected  chain as the given rule number.  So, if the rule number is 1, the rule or rules are
>                 inserted at the head of the chain.  This is also the default if no rule number is specified.